# Organising de-normalised data in redis

Tags: redis

In a Redis database I have a number of hashes corresponding to "story" objects.

I have an ordered set `stories` containing all keys of the above (the stories) enabling convenient retrieval of stories.

I now want to store arbitrary emoticons (ie. the Unicode characters corresponding to "smiley face" etc) with stories as "user emotions" corresponding to the emotion the story made the user feel.

I am thinking of:

- creating new hashes called `emotions` containing single emoticons (one per emotion expressed)
- creating a hash called `story-emotions` that enables efficient retrieval of and counting of all the emotions associated with a story
- creating another new hash called `user-story-emotions` mapping user IDs to items in the story-emotion hash.

Typical queries will be:

- retrieve all the emotions for a story for the current user
- retrieve the count of each kind of emotion for the 50 latest stories

Does this sound like a sensible approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very sensible, but I think I can help make it even more so.

To store the emoticons dictionary, use two Hashes. The first, lets call it `emoticon-id` should have a field for each emoticon expressed. The field name is the actual Unicode sequence and the value is a unique integer value starting from 0, and increasing for each new emoticon added.

Another Hash, `id-emoticon`, should be put in place to do the reverse mapping, i.e. from field names that are ids to actual Unicode values.

This gives you O(1) lookups for emoticons, and you should also consider caching this in your app.

To store the `user-story-emotions` data, look into Redis' Bitmaps. Tersely, use the emoticon id as index to toggle the presence/lack of it by that user towards that story.

Note that in order to keep things compact, you'll want popular emotions to have low ids so your bitmaps remain a small as possible.

To store the aggregative `story-emotions`, the Sorted Set would be a better option. Elements can be either id or actual unicode, and the score should be the current count. This will allow you to fetch the top emoticons (`ZREVRANGEBYSCORE`) and/or page similarly to how you're doing with the recent 50 stories (I assume you're using the `stories` Sorted Set for that).

Lastly, when serving the second query, use pipelining or Lua scripting when fetching the bulk of 50 `story-emotion` counter values in order get more throughput and better concurrency.

Comment: Thank you. Please can you help clarify my understanding? So for the `user-story-emotions` bitmap, you'd have a bitmap per user-story combination. When a user sets an emotion on a story, the bitmap is found (O1, key ==> `user-story-emotions/<story-id>/<user>`) and the bit at position `emoticonId` in that bitmap is set to `1`. So the bitmap corresponds to the emoticons set by a user on a story. To answer the question: "what emoticons has a user applied to this story" you look up the bitmap (O(1)), and somehow (how? walk the bitmap?) find the indices of all the "ones".

Comment: Is there a command to get all the indices set to `1` (i.e. all the emotions expressed by a user against a story)?

Comment: Your understanding is perfect. There is no such command, but you can either GET that bitmap and walk it in the client or use server-side Lua for that.

Comment: Thank you. Does the bitmap automatically accommodate index additions larger than its current size? Is it a sparse array with gaps assumed to be zero?

Comment: Exactly. You should, therefore, try and map popular emoticons to low indices.

Comment: Do I need to maintain a value like `next-emoticon-id` and use the `INCR` command to calculate the next `emoticon-id` or is there a better way?

Comment: You can do that, but if you're doing it in a single Hash, you can just call `HLEN`